# Codec for Mp3 for 12.04 LTS

Tags: codecs

How do I add codecs for  MP3 url streams ?
I am running ubuntu 12.04 with the standard firefox from 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0
```